# freetype use fallback for missing glyphs

Tags: freetype, freetype2

How can I tell freetype to use a fallback font when a string does contain a character that is not present in the Font I'm using as a default?

I need to render non-latin glyphs correctly in my application.

Do I have to manage a fallback myself?

If so: how do I detect if there is a missing glyph in a given string?

Comment: The Unicode Last Resort font is available for [download](http://www.unicode.org/policies/lastresortfont_eula.html).

Comment: The GNU Unifont might serve as a good fallback font, since it contains a glyph for every codepoint in the Basic Multilingual Plane (BMP).  The server seems to be offline at the moment, but you can find its contents archived on [archive.org](https://web.archive.org/web/20160818150027/http://unifoundry.com/).

Comment: I feel like the answers to this question so far are quite poor. Fallback fonts are a concept that is well-implemented in GUIs, and it surprises me that freetype would expect you to reimplement them from nothing. Using a "last resort" font, or pixelated Unifont, does not solve the problem. You want to show a *good* glyph, using an appropriate installed font, not just *any* glyph.

Answer (score 1):

I'm sorry, I don't know if you need to handle fallback yourself, but my guess would be that you do. As for how to detect if there is missing glyph, you could use this method: [FT_Get_Char_index](http://www.freetype.org/freetype2/docs/reference/ft2-base_interface.html#FT_Get_Char_Index) If it returns 0, it means symbol was not found.

Answer (score 1):

The GNU Unifont can serve as a fallback font for every codepoint in the Basic Multilingual Plane (BMP), which would be `0x0000-0xFFFF`.  That should cover the vast majority of what you might encounter.  Available for download [here](http://unifoundry.com/) ([archive](https://web.archive.org/web/20160818150027/http://unifoundry.com/)).

The Unicode Last Resort font can serve as a final fallback for every codepoint in all of the planes.  These glyphs only show broad categories.  Available for download [here](http://www.unicode.org/policies/lastresortfont_eula.html).

It looks like you would have to detect the absence of a glyph with [FT_Get_Char_Index()](https://www.freetype.org/freetype2/docs/reference/ft2-base_interface.html#FT_Get_Char_Index) as SMart [explained](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19065127/5472899), and in those cases turn to Unifont or the Last Resort font.